# Please help me with following the data types

Tags: java, types, abstract-data-type

Assuming you belong to the IT department of the compant, and tasked to write a Java program that uses the object-oriented to do the following task:

IT Class:

There will be a class containing (but not restricted to) the following attributes belongs to computer:

**Computer ID:** 4 characters and/or numbers;

> private string computerid;
>   outcome: Computer ID: D001

**Processor Speed:** Alphanumeric

> private (???) speed;
>   outcome: Speed: 3.2GHZ

**RAM:** Alphanumeric

> private (???) ram;
>   outcome: RAM: 512MB

**Harddisk:** Alphanumeric

> private (???) disk;
>   outcome: disk: 80GB

Comment: You need to look what `alphanumeric` means and you'll know what kind of type you need. On the `double` or `float` you might want to read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598078/float-and-double-datatype-in-java

Answer (score 2):

Alphanumeric should be a string, in this case, that you can compare with a pattern using a regular expression (regex) to make sure it is alphanumeric. Something like this:

```
String alphanumeric='abc123';
alphanumeric.matches('[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}'); //true
```

Comment: my apologies, what's regex?

Comment: @veronica - ask wikipedia