# Evaluating a Ratio Expression

Tags: java

I'm writing a rules engine and one of the expressions the client is looking for is a "less than 1:80"

1:80 being a ratio

Is converting the ratio to a float a wise decision?

```
//psuedo-code
String givenRatio = "1:80";
String[] ratioNums = givenRatio.split(":");
float evalValue = Integer.valueOf(ratioNums[0]) / Integer.valueOf(ratioNums[1]);
```

Comment: Maybe, though I'd probably select double instead of float, BUT, it really depends on how you will use the data as to what precision you need.

Comment: your String givenRatio is missing a double quotes at the end

Comment: What if the given ratio is like 2:84.5 ? then `Integer.valueOf ` will result in information loss, I would suggest `double eval = Double.valueOf( ratio[0])/Double.valueOf(ratio[2])`

Comment: `int` divided by `int` is an `int` (truncated), not a decimal number. In your case, `evalValue` would be assigned the value `0`. You need to cast to `float` *before* dividing.

Comment: As for the question *"is it a wise decision"*, that is entirely depending on how it's used, and answers will be mostly opinion-based.

Answer (score 0):

The division should be by float or double, with int you could lose information or even divide by zero.
And about saving it, it depends. In this case ("1:int") I would have just saved it as a int constant and divide next expressions oppositely (ratioNums[1] by ratioNums[0]) and then compare.
If it should change to expressions different from "1:int" such as "80:1", "2:5", I would keep it in float/double (as much precision as needed) and use the original comparison.

Answer (score 0):

A float gives you approx. 6-7 decimal digits precision while a double gives you approx. 15-16. Also the range of numbers is larger for double.

A double needs 8 bytes of storage space while a float needs just 4 bytes.

[Float and double datatype in java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598078/float-and-double-datatype-in-java)