# Is double the correct datatype to calculate decimal percentage?

Tags: java, android, floating-point

I want to calculate percentage in my project and I am using double for that. Suggest me the correct data type to calculate percentage in decimal like 18% of 5.368 should give 0.966 exact.

I want the result truncated to 3 decimal places.

I am using this:

```
EditText kundan = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.kundan);
double kundangiven = Double.parseDouble(kundan.getText().toString());
EditText loss = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.losspercentage);
double lossinkundan = Double.parseDouble(loss.getText().toString());
losspercent  = (lossinkundan * kundangiven) / 100 ;
losspercent = losspercent % 10 ;
displayTotalloss(losspercent);
```

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598078/float-and-double-datatype-in-java), it might help. Double, btw, is the correct type imho

Comment: What exactly isn't working with your code?

Comment: the result part i want the fraction part as 0.000

Comment: @Rosan See my edited answer below re: formatting the result

Comment: @Rosankarel If what you are looking for is a way to truncate a non-integer number to 3 decimal places, that should be expressed more clearly in the question.  I made a small edit.  I hope that's ok.

Comment: Important question @Rosankarel, does your `displayTotalLoss()` method take a `String` or a `double`?  Also, just to be safe, I think forcing floating point division with `losspercent  = (lossinkundan * kundangiven) / 100.0 ;` is a good idea.

Comment: @Rosankarel what is this line for? `losspercent = losspercent % 10 ;`  All that will do is chop of any digits left of the one's place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your original code works fine regarding storing percentage calculations in doubles. Regarding formatting the result to 3 decimal places, use `String.format()`, e.g.

```
String.format("%.3f", losspercent);
```

Comment: A decimal is a digit. Do you mean decimal *places*?

Comment: it didn't give me the result ...i think its simple decimal division which i cannot code properly.. i have given example..18 %  OF  5.368 should give 0.966

Comment: It's giving me an answer of 0.9662400000000001, which is still correct to 3 decimal places.

Comment: yess but is there any way to descard the rest from 2

Comment: If you're displaying the result in a textview you can use String.format to limit decimal places e.g. `String.format("%.3f", losspercent);`

Comment: thanks @MichaelDodd it really helped and i am getting what i want...thanks

Answer (score 2):

Now that I better understand your needs, this is the way to get a `double` to 3 digits of precision for display:

`String.format("%.3f", losspercent);`

This returns a `String`, so it can be returned from a function, passed directly to your display function, or stored in a variable of type `String`

It sounds like you are asking whether you are using the correct data type to store your computed percentage, or whether there is a better option.

Given your present code structure, I would say that yes, `double` is the right choice.  Any time you are dividing (or multiplying for that matter) non-integer numbers, there is a good chance that an exact result requires a higher level of precision for the output than for the inputs.  The memory cost of using `double` instead of `float` here is probably negligible, so `double` seems like the obvious choice.

If you are really, really concerned about accuracy, then you could use `BigDecimal`.  `BigDecimal` is not a primitive though, so it would cost more in memory and processing (although still probably not noticeable in this example).

Of course, if you really want to use the "right" data type, and you have control over the code base, you could create your own data type.  I think it is unnecessary here though.  `double` is perfectly suitable.  If you are concerned about readability, you may consider creating a function that takes a `double x` and an `int p`, and returns a double representing `p` percent of `x`.