# Convert String to Float preserving decimal places

Tags: java, string

I have some Java Strings formatted as Brazilian money with 4 decimal places, like:

```
1.000.000,0000 (1 million)
3,9590 (3 dollar and 9590 cents)
253,8999
10,0000
```

and so on...

I want to convert it into float so I can do some math with this.

How can I convert Strings to float preserving 4 decimal places? I tried Float.parseFloat() method but I always got NumberFormatException (maybe because of the comma).

Searching on web I only see people who wants to convert Float to formatted String.

Comment: Don't use floats for money related calculation https://stackoverflow.com/a/27598164/6207294

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323502/how-to-set-thousands-separator-in-java

Comment: To prevent number format exception, you can replace the "," with "." and "." with "". This should give you a proper number in decimal format before parsing it as float.

Comment: @ashish2199 please don't do that, there are nice APIs in Java to properly deal with number formatting (see [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56892426/1098603)).

Comment: **Bigdecimal** for *Big Decisions*

Comment: Is `1.000,0000` really one million, or one thousand? It looks like there are two different separators.

Comment: Sorry, I edited my question. 1.000.000,0000 represents 1 million with 4 decimal places, so 1.000.000,1000 represents 1 million and 1 cent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`NumberFormat.parse()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String)):

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getNumberInstance();
float val = nf.parse("3,9590").floatValue();
```

You can give a `Locale` to it when getting the instance, but the default will be your current locale.