# Why different result? float vs double

Tags: java, computer-science, precision

```java
System.out.println(0.1F + 0.2F); // 0.3
System.out.println(0.1D + 0.2D); // 0.30000000000000004
```

I understood 0.1D + 0.2D ~= 0.30000000000000004.
But I guessed these result are same, but it is not.
Why result are different?

Comment: Because `float` and `double` are different. Otherwise they would be the same, and you wouldn't have both of them.

Comment: Looks to me that this question has been asked and answered many times already, for example [Float and double datatype in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598078/float-and-double-datatype-in-java). Did you search for questions that are similar to yours, as described in [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why are the results different?

In a general sense:

- Because the binary representations for `float` and `double` are different.
- Because neither `float` or `double` binary representations have a precise representation for `0.3`.
- Therefore the differences (the errors) between the closest decimal and binary floating point representations for `0.3` are different in `float` versus `double`.

Errors can creep in and/or compound when converting the decimal numbers to binary, when doing the arithmetic, and when converting the binary back to decimal to print out the number.  They are inherent / unavoidable to all computations involving Real numbers and finite numeric representations on a practical computer.

For a broader treatment, read: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

---

Now if you were so inclined, you could examine the binary representations for the numbers here, and work out precisely where the errors are occurring here:

- in the decimal -> binary floating point conversion
- in the floating point arithmetic
- in the binary floating point conversion -> decimal conversion,
- or in more than one of the above.

If you *really* want to dig into it, I suggest that you take a look at `Float.floatToRawIntBits` method and its double precision analog `Double.doubleToRawLongBits`.  These will allow you to examine the binary floating point representations.  You can then manually convert them to *exact* real numbers and work out the errors compared with the "ideal" decimal representations.

It is tedious.