# How to retrieve float from Firestore?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, data-retrieval

Hi I have problem with retrieving data from Firestore. I don't know how to retrieve data from number field with dot.

> For example `Prize : 2.54`

I tried this

```
longPrize = documentSnapshot.getLong("Prize");
```

but it don't work because it's returns only `2`. I have to get `2.54` as result.
How I can do this ? Unfortunately Firebase don't support retrieving data in float form (`getFloat()` doesn't exist).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you have a floating point number in a document field, you can use [getDouble()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getDouble(java.lang.String)) to access it as a Double.  If you want to cast that to a float, that's up to you.

Also read: [Float and double datatype in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27598078/float-and-double-datatype-in-java)